# Update a line in the AD info field

Tags: regex, powershell

I have slight problem.

We have a PowerShell script that sets an expiration date in the 'Notes:' field in the AD.

What i want to do is to be able to remove/update this w/o removing other data in the field.

Example of 'Notes:' field (for ie. user X):

```
GR1234567890 expires on 20251125
END
```

If i use following code to try and isolate everything but the line starting with GR in it.

```
$UserName = Get-ADUser -Filter {SAMAccountName -eq "X"} -Properties Info
$UserName.Info | Select-String -Pattern 'GR[\s\S].+' -NotMatch
```

I get a "full match" and no output at all.

And if i remove -NotMatch i get a full match and full output of 'Notes:' field.

I've tried the RegEx in some of the RegEx online testers out there and there it works as expected. It is like there are no LF/CR or some wierd encoding on the output when traversing the pipeline...

I could do a match GR, a date and everything in between i guess... but id like for knowledge sake want to know if the above thinking is not possible or totally wrong (RegEX is not my strongest suit).

Comment: To match `GR` at the start of a string/line, use `'^GR'`. The `'GR[\s\S].+'` matches `GR` anywhere in the string and `[\s\S]` matches any char and `.+` matches any 1+ chars. However, the problem is with the Powershell code.

Comment: I thought that [\s\S] would match any whitespace and none whitespace character "forever" (+) until a either a LF or CR (.) came up?

Comment: No, `GR[\s\S]+` would, you quantified a *dot*.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Was code indead. If I used a -Replace on a variable it worked better... since (i guess) Select-String matches a whole string that contains what i ask for.

Comment: You may post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was indeed the code itself as pointed out by Wiktor. Hats of to him.

```
$UserName.Info -Replace '^GR.+'
```

Will remove the line i want removed.